# Sending parameters from return statement to path in Django

Tags: python, django

Currently, I am using this code to render a page:

```
return render(request, 'appname/bundles_edit.html', context)
```

This works fine. However, I would like to send two integers to my path:

```
path('bundles/<int:bundle_template_number>/<int:bundle_id>/', views.bundles_edit, name='bundles_item'),
```

How would I insert those two integers in my return render statement?

Edit: 
Views Functions:

```
def bundles(request):
    context = {}
    if 'bundle_to_edit' in request.POST:
        bundle = request.POST['bundle_to_edit']
        instance_as_list = bundle.split(',')
        template_number = instance_as_list[0]
        template_id = instance_as_list[1]
        return render(request, 'contractor/bundles_edit.html' + '/' + template_number + '/' + template_id,, context)
    return render(request, 'contractor/bundles.html, context)

def bundles_edit(request):
    context= {}
    return render(request, 'contractor/bundles_edit.html', context)
```

I know the first return render is wrong, but I am not sure how to do it properly.

Edit 2: Updated code.

```
def bundles(request):
    if 'bundle_to_edit' in request.POST:
        bundle = request.POST['bundle_to_edit']
        instance_as_list = bundle.split(',')
        template_number = instance_as_list[0]
        bundle_id = instance_as_list[1]
        context['bundle_template_number'] = template_number
        context['bundle_id'] = bundle_id
        return render(request, 'contractor/bundles_edit.html', context)
    return render(request, 'contractor/bundles.html, context)


def bundles_edit(request, bundle_template_number, bundle_id):
    context= {}
    context['bundle_template_number'] = bundle_template_number
    context['bundle_id'] = bundle_id
    return render(request, 'contractor/bundles_edit.html', context)

urls.py:
path('bundles/<int:bundle_template_number>/<int:bundle_id>/', views.bundles_edit, name='bundles_item'),
```

Everything works at this point, it just leaves me with the browser URL as: /contractor/bundles/ instead of /contractor/bundles/1/8/

Comment: It's not clear what do you exactly mean. Do you need to pass this values to template? Do you see any errors? Can you show full view code?

Comment: Essentially, I want this to url to be created: website.com/appname/bundles/2/3. I just want to insert those two numbers. Here is pseudocode of what I want: return render(request, 'appname/bundles_edit.html'/2/3, context). If I do that, it says TemplateDoesNotExist at 'appname/bundles_edit.html/2/3.

Comment: Sure. I will add it to the question.

Comment: So from `bundles` view you want to redirect to `bundles_edit` view?

Comment: You seem to be confusing `render()` and `redirect()` and the template path with the url arguments. You certainly want to read the doc about urls and the `reverse()` function (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

Comment: You are correct. That fixed my issue. Now it redirects and shows up properly in the URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that your path is good, like they said in the docs :

```
path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.index)
```

```
def index(request, year, month):
    ...
    year = Years.objects.get(pk=year)
    month = Months.objects.get(pk=month)
    return render(request, 'yourtamplate.html', {'year':year, 'month':month})
```

Is that your idea?

Comment: Yes, that is my idea. That works. Thanks! I notice it doesn't show up in the URL when I land on the final page. (in my browser URL).  Is that just the way it is, or is there a way to make it show up in the URL? For instance if I was to copy and paste the url it gives me, it doesn't include the parameters.

Comment: Hmm, as I remember, it should be visible in the URL bar of your browser. 

Can you update the code, with your current code, so I can see it?

Comment: I took what @bruno-desthuilliers said and that fixed the issue on the URL showing up in the browser.

Comment: Great, I wanted to suggest the same! Glad that you managed it to work.